Youtube Data API v3 - Update "notifySubscribers" property of video
I'm currently automating scheduling for publication videos in draft mode using Youtube Data API v3 in NodeJS. I do not want to notify subscribers when the video is published, so I want to disable "Publish to subscriptions feed and notify subscribers". When using videos.insert, it can be set using notifySubscribers in the options.
However, once the video is inserted, and only videos.update is available to edit the video, notifySubscribers does not have any effect on the video.
This is my attempt, using notifySubscribers that works for inserts, but not for updates
google.youtube('v3').videos.update({
  access_token: 'my_access_token',
  part: ['snippet,status'],

  /* This has no effect. */
  notifySubscribers: false, 

  /* These fields are updated as expected. */
  requestBody: {
    id: 'my_video_id',
    snippet: {
      categoryId: '24',
      title: 'My title',
      description: 'My description',
    },
    status: {
      madeForKids: false,
      selfDeclaredMadeForKids: false,
      privacyStatus: 'private',
      publishAt: '...',
    },
  },
});

My question is: How to change the notifySubscribers property of an existing unpublished video using the Youtube Data API v3?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert explicitly mentions notifySubscribers as one of the optional parameters, whereas https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update doesn't. So I would take that to mean, that it is not currently possible to set this when updating an already existing video.
